# Receiving Kafka event on web browser real time

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka

We are using Kafka cluster for sending/receiving messages at real time. We are able to publish messages to Kafka topics successfully. Now we want to receive these messages real time on a Single Page Application (SPA) running on a web browsers using JavaScript. Is it possible to push messages to SPA running on latest version any famous browser directly from Kafka? I found examples of receiving messages realtime using NodeJS but none with the JavaScript running on web browser.

Comment: I don't think you can consume Kafka messages directly in java script , you should have server side technology to consume the messages as per my understanding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are Javascript clients for Kafka but given the description of your use case I would recommend you either use a REST or WebSocket proxy between your browser side javascript and Kafka. That will ensure the message can traverse any intermediate firewalls.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code or direct me to some examples of the implementation you are suggesting?

Comment: The Confluent REST Proxy is open source (see https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest) and can be called directly from Javascript in the browser. There is already a nice JS wrapper on the REST API for nodejs (see https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest-node) which you might be able to browserify.

Comment: For websockets you might want to look at the Play Framework and Akka Streams (see demo https://www.jamesward.com/2016/05/25/combining-reactive-streams-heroku-kafka-and-play-framework/)