# Sending message from Spring Kafka to Angular

Tags: spring, angular, apache-kafka

Is there a way to send message from Spring Kafka to Angular without using Websocket?

I use Spring as service side, and Angular as Client side.

When, I send a Kafka message from Spring server-side, I just want to transmit this message to Angular based client side.

I used this code in Spring-server to send message:

kafkaTemplate.send(topic, payload);

Actually my question is nearly same of this:
Actually my question is nearly same of this:
[Receiving Kafka event on web browser real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253531/receiving-kafka-event-on-web-browser-real-time)

Comment: Can you please detail your situation further?

Comment: I use Spring as service side, and Angular as Client side.

 When, I send a Kafka message from Spring server-side, I just want to transmit this message to Angular based client side.

  I used this code in Spring-server to send message:

   kafkaTemplate.send(topic, payload);

Comment: Could you edit your question to include that information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Kafka REST API (proxy), it lets you to call Kafka directly from you client javascript and so you could consume/send events directly.

Have a look: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest

Comment: As far as I understand, it supports only node.js currently.
So, if I decide to use Kafka REST API then do I have to integrate with node.js?

Comment: I think the question is not correct, you should't integrate with anything, you just install REST PROXY and then could call it from your javascript. Thats it.

Comment: So communication will be interactive, namely bidirectional from JS to Rest Proxy and from Rest Proxy to JS, right?

Comment: Actually my question is nearly same of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253531/receiving-kafka-event-on-web-browser-real-time